# Keras: Strange artifacts in images produced by ImageDataGenerator

Tags: keras

I've instructed data generator to output  generated images.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1. / 255,
        rotation_range=180,  # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
        width_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
        height_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,  # randomly flip images
        vertical_flip=True
    ) 

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        os.path.join(train_base, train_dir),
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary',
        color_mode='grayscale',
        save_to_dir=gen_train_dir,
    )
```

In the output directory I#ve found after the run some images with strange artifacts. On the picture belof I've marked only one with a yellow circuit, but I think it is obvious, which other cells contain unnatural line-artifacts.

[image]

Why do they appear?

I suspect they influence the accuracy.

Comment: You should include the code that instantiates your train_generator, the parameters there are important for the question

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro: Ok, thanks! Added. I've started to deactivate the functions one by one, and suspect  the rotation or the combination of some functions. The artifacts are not in all images, even rotated.

Answer (score 2):

The artifacts you see are caused by the generator. When scaling/rotating/shifting, the new image will need to "fill" some pixels that didn't exist in the original image. By default the way if `fill_mode="nearest` so it take just the closest pixel to fill it.

You may want to test the other modes if they are more appropriate to your problem. [All options can be found here](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)